# I'm working on a desktop application to manage a bibliotheque

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to create a datagridview to accept value in Arabic and display this values in text box in C#.

Here is a example of when i try to enter values in Arabic:

[image: here is a example of when i try to enter values in arabic]

Comment: [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487295/how-can-i-display-a-unicode-string-in-the-column-header-of-a-datagridview) Default font does not support these characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display a Unicode string in the column header of a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487295/how-can-i-display-a-unicode-string-in-the-column-header-of-a-datagridview)

Comment: Try this Nuget library to simplify Ado.net code  : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity